# How can this error be rectified

Tags: c#, remoting, vpn

How can this error be rectified?

Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Message: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
Source: mscorlib

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(String hostName)
   at System.Net.Dns.Resolve(String hostName)

Answer (score 2):

That depends entirely on what code is causing it. If it is an explicit call to System.Net.Dns.Resolve, it's probably a failure on the part of the DNS server. Wrap the offending code in a try-catch block to catch SocketException and handle such events gracefully. Otherwise, without seeing any code, it's impossible to know.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when trying to connect to an SFTP site.

I removed the trailing '/' from the URL (sftp://127.0.0.1/) and connected successfully.

This might not be the problem you are experiencing, but I hope it inspires you to "try the simple changes".

Answer (score 0):

use IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(string HostName);